# Connecting to the internet with ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, bluetooth, connection

I just installed the newest ubuntu, the 11.10 version. I was using mandriva and windows 7 ultimate. I dont know how to connect the laptop with the internet in the following ways. some one please help
1. tried to connect via bluetooth in my phone. I was using internet, using the same phone and connection, and laptop in mandriva
2. I have plugged in a wired connection. The system detects it, but dosent start a connection.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you have an Android device (from 2.2 or rooted 2.1), you can enable Wifi tethering and Ubuntu recognize it instantly; then you insert the shared password and you're done; if you want to connect exclusively by bluetooth, then you should take a look to these 2 offical guides:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothDialup

If you have an iPhone, here is a program that lets you tether with it:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/ipheth-utils/

2) When you plug in a network cable connected to a router, Ubuntu recognize it without problems and you can browse the internet after less than one second; so I think this should be a problem with your router or external modem.